# How to retrive matching id record using while loop in java

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I am able to retrieve data from database using while loop but i am getting all records from table not currently matching id record with where clause.

Comment: You probably _might_ want to share some more details. We're good but we're not that good. :)

Answer (score 0):

Question is not so clear Vijay, Eventhough this might be you are looking for. Incase of while loop, go with if condition. This might work.

```
   if(resultset.next){
    //your condition
    }
```